# Insert spaces into a PHP array variable

Tags: php, wordpress

The following code:

```
<?php $terms = get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'projects' ); 
      $terms = strip_tags( $terms );?>
<?php echo $terms ?>
```

Produces the following result:

```
CateringCommercialHospitality
```

Note the lack of spaces. How do I insert spaces so the output will be:

```
Catering Commercial Hospitality
```

**EDIT**

`get_the_term_list` outputs the following:

```
<a href="http://permalink" rel="tag">Commercial</a>
```

Comment: if they're wrapped in HTML tags then you probably need to get the text content via the DOM since any solution after you've stripped the tags will break in case there's inner spaces.

Comment: What is the result of `get_the_term_list`?

Comment: @m7913d Please see updated answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one way is to use before after property :

```
<?php echo get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'people', 'People: ', ', ' ); ?>
```

another way, which I used for my project :

```
function findarch_portfolio_categories() {

      $terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'portfolio-category' );
      if(!empty($terms)){
      $portfolio_category_links = array();

      foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
          $portfolio_category_links[] = $term->name;
      }
      $on_portfolio_category = join( ", ", $portfolio_category_links );
      return sprintf( esc_html__( '%s', 'textdomain' ), esc_html( $on_portfolio_category ) );
    }
  }
  endif;
```

Comment: The before and after property did the trick for me. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty you could do `$terms = $terms.replace(/([A-Z])/g, ' $1').trim()`. Add space before every capital and strip trailing/leading spaces

Comment: This seems to just break the page completely.